# Можно ли организовать перебор токенов цикла вложенным циклом в бат-файле?

Tags: cmd, bat

Или как почистить строку от лишних символов, если заранее не известно расположение и количество нужных слов и не нужных символов?..
Поясню на примере, который, к слову естественно, не работает ).. не удачная попытка организовать перебор токенов одного цикла другим, на предмет наличия в них значения. Буду признателен, если кто-то хоть что-то предложит )

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
chcp 65001 >nul

set str=[ word word:word?word#word word... ]

for /f "tokens=1-12 delims=[]:?# " %%1 in ("%str%") do (
    for /l %%a in (1,1,12) do (
        echo %%%%a
    )
)

pause
exit
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Первоначальная задача: это избавиться от лишних символов, или найти только нужные слова, или иное? Цель?

Comment: Цель избавиться от лишних символов, количество и расположение которых заранее не известно, при этом оставить слова. Их количество также не известно. В идеале еще убрать пробелы в начале и конце строки, пробелов тоже может оказаться сколько угодно

Comment: Что считается лишними символам, что становится словами - пример?

Comment: Лишние символы те, которые нельзя использовать в именах каталогов в дальнейшем /\|*?:"

Comment: Это если строго, но я бы еще поудалял некоторые другие например #%^&№ и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Методом научного тыка добился примерно следующего:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
chcp 65001 >nul

set old_str=[long **long:: #\text and more /more "more]
set new_str=
set symbols=[ ] # \ ^^^| / : * ^^^" 

:loop
for %%l in ("!old_str:~%n%,1!") do (
    set letter=%%~l
    if not "!letter!"=="" ( 
        for %%s in (%symbols%) do (
            if "!letter!" EQU "%%s" set letter=
        )
        set new_str=!new_str!!letter!
        set /a n+=1
        goto :loop
    )
)
echo Text: %new_str%

pause >nul
exit
ENDLOCAL
```

Побуквенно пересобирает строку исключая заданные символы. Делает практически то что нужно, но не работает с & - ? - % - $ - эти знаки ведут себя как-то странно. Плюс осталась не решенной проблема удаления лишних пробелов...